# Generate diff from SVN branch history

Tags: svn

I committed changes from working copy to a branch.

How can I see a diff of the committed changes, preferably, without specifying exact revision numbers?

Answer (score 0):

You will always be comparing to a specific version (even if you do not specify it).

For example

```
svn diff /path/to/trunk /path/to/branch
```

Will compare the checkout version on trunk with the checkout version in the branch.

Or you can compare the two paths in the actual repository, the command will be the same. almost..

```
svn diff url/to/trunk url/to/branch
```

You can also combine these, so you compare between an url and a local copy or vice versa.

I'm giving quite a generic answer since your question isn't very specific. For example, you do not mention if you are using some sorts of a gui (TortoiseSVN, KDEsvn, etc) or the command-line interface (which I highly recommend using) like in the samples above.

If you wondering why I recommend using the cli, it is because it is the same on linux, mac and windows. So learn it ones and you can use it anywhere. This goes for most tools that has a command-line interface.

Also I recommend reading the documentation: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/

Comment: I'm using the CLI. I'm looking for kind of a shortcut command to get a diff between branch base and head without going into extracting specific version numbers from log.

Comment: You can mix working copy paths and urls in the same command. In case you have no local modifications then *svn diff /path/to/branch url/to/trunk* would be a diff between the base of the branch and the head of trunk. However if you have local modifications those will also be part of the diff.